# How can I exchange an item and a spacer?

Tags: qt, alignment, visibility

In qt, I have a form that contains among other things, a group with

- A combo box
- a checkbox
- a spacer
- a button
  Based on some logic, I want sometimes to show another combo box... Where the spacer is, but smaller.

When I add it though, everything resizes automatically

I don't see a way to make it invisible, and yet keep items of the same size when I make it visible again.

I tried making it fixed size... But unless I use fixed sizes and positioning for everything, which I think is a bad idea, the items still move around when I change visibility.

It seems silly... But how can I make my little combo box show up instead of the spacer not next to it ? Spacers don't seem to have a name...

I would do

```
combo.setVisible(condition);
Spacer.setVisible(!condition);
```

Very easy... Except how do I access the spacer from code ?

Comment: Please post a code snippet showing how the widgets and the spacer are created and added to a parent/layout.

Comment: The form was created with Qt Designer, so I technically had no code to show... but thanks to your comment I looked in the xml that was designed and saw the spacer name ... which I had not been able to see in the properties window earlier. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to use a container `QWidget` instead of the spacer. Here is how it will look:

```
A combo box
a checkbox
a widget-container
a button
```

Widget-container is a `QWidget` with **fixed size**. Put your combo-box there and it will maintain it's size when you show/hide the combo-box.

Regarding your question (You will not need it but just to know in the future):

> how do I access the spacer from code

You can create a spacer from code like this:

```
QSpacerItem* spacer = new QSpacerItem(0, 15, QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
layout->addItem(spacer);
...
```

Also you can get it from a layout if you know its index:

```
QLayoutItem* item = layout->itemAt(index);
```

But there is no such method as `show/hide` for layout items.

Comment: The Widget is perfect - and no coding needed, a 5 second fix :-) awesome